# Adding 90000 XElement to XDocument

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, linq-to-xml

I have a `Dictionary<int, MyClass>`

It contains 100,000 items

10,000 items value is populated whilst 90,000 are null.

I have this code:

```
var nullitems = MyInfoCollection.Where(x => x.Value == null).ToList();
nullitems.ForEach(x => LogMissedSequenceError(x.Key + 1));

private void LogMissedSequenceError(long SequenceNumber)
        {
            DateTime recordTime = DateTime.Now;

            var errors = MyXDocument.Descendants("ERRORS").FirstOrDefault();
            if (errors != null)
            {

                errors.Add(
                    new XElement("ERROR",
                        new XElement("DATETIME", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff")),
                        new XElement("DETAIL", "No information was read for expected sequence number " + SequenceNumber),
                        new XAttribute("TYPE", "MISSED"),
                        new XElement("PAGEID", SequenceNumber)
                        )
                );
            }
        }
```

This seems to take about 2 minutes to complete. I can't seem to find where the bottleneck might be or if this timing sounds about right?

Can anyone see anything to why its taking so long?

Comment: Use debug Trace to see how long the query takes, and how long the logging takes. Also, XML might have a lot of processing overhead when processing a 100,000-items document.

Comment: Did you run a profiler? I'd be interested at why you run DateTime.now twice (as it's relatively expensive to call) and how slow it really is when called 90k times...

Comment: I've removed the DateTime and only call it once and pass it as a string.  I haven't got Visual Studio Team etc with the Profiler in it.

Comment: If you check you will probably find that looking up the "ERRORS" element on every call is one of the most expensive parts.  Either pass in the ERRORS element to the method or use LINQ to your advantage as I noted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about replacing the method call with a LINQ query?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var MyInfoCollection = (from key in Enumerable.Range(0, 100000)
                            let value = (MoreRandom() % 10 != 0)
                                                    ? (string)null
                                                    : "H"
                            select new { Value = value, Key = key }
                           ).ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);

    var MyXDocument = new XElement("ROOT",
                                    new XElement("ERRORS")
                                  );
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    //===
    var errorTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff");
    var addedIndex = MyInfoCollection.Select((item, index) =>
                                                    new
                                                    {
                                                        Value = item.Value,
                                                        Key = item.Key,
                                                        Index = index
                                                    });
    var errorQuery = from item in addedIndex
                     where string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Value)
                     let sequenceNumber = item.Key + 1
                     let detail = "No information was read for expected " +
                                  "sequence number " + sequenceNumber
                     select new XElement("ERROR",
                        new XElement("DATETIME", errorTime),
                        new XElement("DETAIL", detail),
                        new XAttribute("TYPE", "MISSED"),
                        new XElement("PAGEID", sequenceNumber)
                        );

    var errors = MyXDocument.Descendants("ERRORS").FirstOrDefault();
    if (errors != null)
        errors.Add(errorQuery);
    //===
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds); //623
}
static RandomNumberGenerator rand = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
static int MoreRandom()
{
    var buff = new byte[1];
    rand.GetBytes(buff);
    return buff[0];
}
```

Comment: @Jon: the "let" allows you assign a contextual variable.  It's like create a variable assignment inside of the foreach loop.  You could put the same information in the "select" statement, but I find this model to be much easier to understand and reuse.

Comment: I also did a test with using the DateTime.Now inside of the LINQ query.  It does slightly slow down the process, but nothing like looking up the "ERRORS" element over and over.

Comment: Thanks! On the PageID element instead of sequence number I need the position in the collection.  Is that possible?

Comment: @Jon: the sequenceNumber on the let statement is calculated the same way as your example.  But there is an overload for .Select that allow you to get the position of the item in the IEnumerable<> set.  I will add an example to my answer.

Comment: @Jon: I updated my example to include using the postion out of the IEnumerable<> set.

Answer (score 3):

If your `MyInfoCollection` is huge, I wouldn't call `ToList()` on it just so you can use the `ForEach` extension method. Calling `ToList()` is going to create and populate a huge list. I'd remove the `ToList()` call, and make the `.ForEach` into a `for each` statement, or write a .`ForEach` extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`.

Then profile it and see how long it takes. One other thing to do is remove the find and null check of the `ERRORS` element. If it's not there, then don't call the `for each` statement above. That way you null check it one time instead of 90,000 times.

Plus as Michael Stum pointed out, I'd define a string to hold the value `DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff")`, then reference it or pass it in. Plus, you don't even use this call:

```
DateTime recordTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: So far I have just implemented the foreach loop rather than the ForEach extension method and they seem the same speed. The ToList() was quick its just the logging taking the time.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would most likely do.

```
private void BuildErrorNodes()
{
    const string nodeFormat = @"<ERROR TYPE=""MISSED""><DATETIME>{0}</DATETIME><DETAIL>No information was read for expected sequence number {1}</DETAIL><PAGEID>{1}</PAGEID></ERROR>";

    var sb = new StringBuilder("<ERRORS>");
    foreach (var item in MyInfoCollection)
    {
        if (item.Value == null) 
        {
            sb.AppendFormat(
                nodeFormat,
                DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff"),
                item.Key + 1
            );
        }
    }

    sb.Append("</ERRORS>");

    var errorsNode = MyXDocument.Descendants("ERRORS").FirstOrDefault();
    errorsNode.ReplaceWith(XElement.Parse(sb.ToString()));
}
```